# Erro de acesso ao caminho foi negado

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com um programa criado em Visual Studio / Windows Forms. Nele acesso o seguinte arquivo para pegar algumas informações:

1º Código (funciona normal)

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@ "E:\OneDrive\VisualStudio\codigosAIH\codigosAIH\bin\Debug\tb_cid.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Alterei o código para que o programa busque o arquivo na pasta de instalação:

2º Código (dá erro de acesso negado)

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + @"\tb_cid.txt"), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Fazendo assim, recebo o erro de Acesso ao caminho foi negado. Já usei um MessageBox pra confirmar o caminho e está correto.

Não creio que seja problema de permissão, senão eu não conseguiria acessar da forma do primeiro código.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Qual é o primeiro exemplo?

Comment: me refiro ao primeiro código com o endereço escrito completo

Comment: Só tem um trechinho de código aí, ele é o primeiro? Se é, qual é o segundo?

Comment: alterei o post, peço que olhe novamente ^^

Comment: Você está querendo abrir o txt?

Comment: sim, quero ler o arquivo. (não postei o resto do código porque tudo funciona normal, apenas essa linha dá erro quando tento pegar o path do arquivo)

Comment: Por favor, pare de usar a tag `visual-studio` nas suas perguntas que não são sobre o Visual Studio =D

Comment: sinceramente agora achei que deveria usar. desculpe mais uma vez

Comment: O primeiro não é um código, é um endereço solto. Se você colocar isso e tentar compilar com C# vai dar erro porque isso não é um código.

Comment: entendi. me referi da forma errada. corrigi novamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Path.GetDirectoryName`** retorna o diretório de um determinado caminho.

Então, isso

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "\tb_cid.txt");
```

vai retornar o caminho **sem o nome do arquivo**. Apenas coloque o parêntese no lugar certo.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString()) + @"\tb_cid.txt";
```

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez, resolveu sim